# Postgres SQL Query to total column with multiple filters

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table that contains a date and status field.  I want to create a query that will return the date, plus the total number of records and then the total number of records for each status on that date.

Source Table:

job_id, process_datetime, process_status

The results I would like:

```
process_date | total_925_jobs  |  total_completed_925_jobs
2022-01-02   |   50            |         45
2022-01-03   |   150           |         135
```

I tried to join to subqueries, but it does not like the calculated date field.

```
SELECT
date(all_records.create_datetime) AS process_date, 
total_jobs.total_925_jobs,
total_completed.total_completed_925_jobs        
    
from "925-FilePreprocessing"
 all_records

INNER JOIN 

(   SELECT 
date("925-FilePreprocessing".create_datetime) AS total_process_date, 
    "925-FilePreprocessing".process_status, 
    COUNT("925-FilePreprocessing".file_preprocessing_id) as total_925_jobs
FROM
    "925-FilePreprocessing"
where 
"925-FilePreprocessing".create_datetime > '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY
total_process_date, process_status
) as "total_jobs"
ON  date(all_records.create_datetime)  = date(total_jobs.total_process_date)

INNER JOIN 

(SELECT
    date("925-FilePreprocessing".create_datetime) AS completed_process_date,    
    COUNT("925-FilePreprocessing".file_preprocessing_id) as total_completed_925_jobs
FROM
    "925-FilePreprocessing"
where 
"925-FilePreprocessing".create_datetime > '2022-01-01'

and ("925-FilePreprocessing".process_status = 'completed'
or "925-FilePreprocessing".process_status = 'completed-duplicated'
or "925-FilePreprocessing".process_status = 'completed-duplicated-published'
or "925-FilePreprocessing".process_status = 'completed-not_a_drawing'
)
GROUP BY
completed_process_date
) as "total_completed"
ON  all_records.process_date = total_completed.completed_process_date


ORDER BY
process_date
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  column all_records.process_date does not exist
LINE 42: ON  all_records.process_date = total_completed.completed_pro...
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Conditional count may be usefull

Old way (using sum)  - before `Postgresql 9.4`

```sql
select 
  a.process_datetime::DATE,
  count(*) total_925_jobs, 
  sum ( case when a.process_status in ('completed', 
                                       'completed-duplicated', 
                                       'completed-duplicated-published', 
                                       'completed-not_a_drawing') 
             then 1 
             else 0 end) total_completed_925_jobs
from "925-FilePreprocessing" a
     where a.process_datetime::DATE >= '2021-01-01'
     group by a.process_datetime::DATE
```

New way - from `POstgresql 9.4` (using `filter`)

```
select 
  a.process_datetime::DATE,
  count(*) total_925_jobs, 
  count(*) filter (where a.process_status in ('completed', 'completed-duplicated', 'completed-duplicated-published', 'completed-not_a_drawing')) total_completed_925_jobs
from "925-FilePreprocessing" a
     where a.process_datetime::DATE >= '2021-01-01'
     group by a.process_datetime::DATE
```

Going back to your query - I have error `column 925-FilePreprocessing.create_datetime does not exist` which is different than yours. Check if table definition you deliver is complete.

Answer (score 0):

the result you like

> ```
> process_date | total_925_jobs  |  total_completed_925_jobs
> 2022-01-02   |   50            |         45
> 2022-01-03   |   150           |         135
> ```

since total_completed have far less row than total_jobs means that there are only two date/datetime greater than '2022-01-01'.

the follow query can be get your result. I declutter a lot unnecessary code.
group by 1 mean: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-group-by-expression/

```
WITH total_jobs AS (
    SELECT
        create_datetime::date AS total_process_date,
        process_status,
        COUNT(file_preprocessing_id) AS total_925_jobs
    FROM
        "925-FilePreprocessing"
    WHERE
        create_datetime::date > '2022-01-01'::date
    GROUP BY
        1,
        2
),
total_completed AS (
    SELECT
        date("925-FilePreprocessing".create_datetime) AS completed_process_date,
        COUNT(file_preprocessing_id) AS total_completed_925_jobs
    FROM
        "925-FilePreprocessing"
    WHERE
        create_datetime::date > '2022-01-01'
        AND process_status IN ('completed', 'completed-duplicated', 'completed-duplicated-published', 'completed-not_a_drawing')
    GROUP BY
        1
)
SELECT
    total_jobs. *,
    tp.total_completed_925_jobs
FROM
    total_jobs tk
    JOIN total_completed tp ON tk.total_process_date = tp.completed_process_date
```